# how to get the TextFiled value outside the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

the TextFiled class

```dart
class InputContainer extends StatefulWidget{

  final _InputContainerInner input = new _InputContainerInner();
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return input;
  }


}

class _InputContainerInner extends State<InputContainer>{
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String num = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    ...
        child: TextField(
         ...
         controller: controller,
         ...
         )
     )
}
```

i use it in another file

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InputContainer passWord = new InputContainer();
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
                passWord,
                new MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        print(passWord.input);
                        print(passWord.input.num);

                    }
                )
            ]
        )
}
```

i click the button , but got nothing of this TextFiled, print result is

```
flutter: InputContainerInner#9818c(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
flutter:
```

maybe it is the matter of lifecycle, but i have made it in the widget , what happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U can save it in some variable e.g.

```
String password = controller.text
```

then call it from other class by creating object or something

Comment: have used this variable to save it ,but still can't get it , 
i wonder this way to create TextFiled Object (by new class)  only can get its created variable ,
if i input some value, inside the textfiled widget , i can get the input value(the `num` get the input , but don't know how to sent it to outside, if i use `ObjectInstance.controller.text`  to  access the value , it seem the widget is not mounted

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't create a new instance of InputContainer in the other widget class, it's wrong.

The ideal way is to use inheritedwidget or scopedmodel,provider but that is more complicated

You can try creating a globalkey inside the other class and access the InputContainerInner text controller from there

Note: Change your _InputContainerInner to InputContainerInner

```
//put this inside your class widget, where u declare all the variables
final GlobalKey<InputContainerInner> containerKey;


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
                //import the inputContainer class
                InputContainer(),
                new MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        print(widget.containerKey.currentState.controller.text);
                        print(widget.containerKey.currentState.controller.input.num);

               }
            )
        ]
    )
```

}

Comment: i tried your answer ,
the`passWord.containerKey` is `[LabeledGlobalKey<InputContainerInner>#e7ac7]`
but when i print the `passWord.input.containerKey.currentState` , the result is `null`, so i wonder if it is the matter of widget lifecycle. otherwise, i use ScopedModel to save the input and get the input value outside the widget

Comment: I see, thanks. Since using scopedmodel is working, i guess you can stick using it. The other way i can think of is setting your text controller to static type, then access it directly.

Comment: i need to reuse the TextField class ,so the instance should have their own controller ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **full example**

```
TextEditingController completeAddressController = new TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
          controller: completeAddressController,
          ),
```

> get value of TextFormField

String text = completeAddressController.text.toString(),

Comment: i have used your way in my initial code and can't get the input value, so i ask this question, hh